# problem in attribute of an object in python

Tags: python, module, attributes, attributeerror

When I am trying to use attribute, then a error comes

```
AttributeError: type object 'Question' has no attribute 'prompt'
```

But this is my code

```
from hello import Question
questions=[
Question(question_sample[0],'a'),
Question(question_sample[1],'a'),
Question(question_sample[2],'a')
]


def run_test(test):
    score=0
    for question in test:
        answer=input(Question.prompt)
        if answer==Question.answer:
        score+=1
    print('you got'+str(score)+'/'+str(len(question_sample)))

run_test(questions)
```

And the module that i made is

```
class Question:
def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
    self.prompt=prompt
    self.answer=answer
```

Kindly help why the error is coming`

```
from project import Test

question_sample=["(1)What is facebook?\n(a)Social network\n(b)Toy\n(c)News website\n(d)Mobile\n\n",
'(2)What is Apple Inc.?\n(a)Social network\n(b)Toy\n(c)News website\n(d)Mobile Company\n\n',
'(3)What is Barbie?\n(a)Social network\n(b)Toy\n(c)News website\n(d)Mobile\n\n']

Questions=[
    Test(question_sample[0], 'a'),
    Test(question_sample[1], 'd'),
    Test(question_sample[2], 'b')
    ]


def exam(x):
    Score=0
    for question in x:
        answer=input(question.question)
        if answer==question.answer:
            Score+=1
    print('you got')
```

I am actually having this problem from a long time.
                `

Comment: It's `answer=input(question.prompt)`, not `...(Question.prompt)`.

Comment: Oh thats a silly mistake...thanks a lot...actually handling a large code is a tough task.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are experiencing a very silly issue. (it happens)
Simply replace `Question` inside your `for` loop with `question` (small letter q)

```py
for question in test:
  answer=input(question.prompt)
  if answer==question.answer:
    score+=1
```

Also, you need an indentation after your `if answer==question.answer:` sentence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pls help me a littile more as i have edited the question

Answer (score -1):

with the for loop `for question in test` you've secretly renamed all `Question(...,...)` to **question** so access them using **question**

thus the loop should be

```
for question in test:
    answer = question.prompt
```

Comment: i am having another problem as mentoined in the question above ..pls help me